# Config test failed when restarting Apache 2

Tags: apache2

```
 ServerAdmin admin@creansys.com
ServerName  creansys.com
ServerAlias www.creansys.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/creansys.com/public_html
<Directory / >
Options FollowSymLinks
Allow Override  All

</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Allow Override All
Order Allow,Deny
allow From all

</Directory>
```

When i tried to  restart apache i got following error
Syntax error
allow and deny must be followed by 'from'.
Action 'configtest' failed.

can anybody help me with a solution

Comment: @muru any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some typos in your configuration:

Use

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride  All
</Directory>
```

and

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After that you should see

```
% apachectl configtest               
Syntax OK
```

Why? Because I've tested it on my system, especially for you. **;)**

Comment: Great, time to accept the answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer **;)**

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines of codes anywhere in the `httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride  All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the answer already given.